# Making a Windows game on a Mac with unity posting to gamejolt, what do I do to post the file when there are many other files and folders?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game with unity on a Mac but the build will be for windows. After I build the game I was ready to post it but I did not know what files in the folder I should post, if I need all the files in the folder what should I do? Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: There should be an `exe` named whatever you told Unity and a `_Data` folder that also has that name. You need both of those (which should also be the only things in the output directory if it was originally empty), plus any other external files that your specific project relies on (no except you can identify these files as they are specific to the project, but by default this list is zero).